# basic spinner example

Tags: android, android-spinner

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/spin"
        android:entries="@array/num"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:text="Click ME"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/txtv"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Spin.java**

```
package com.and.spin;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class spin extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtv);

        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        final Spinner s=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                            
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String spin=s.toString();
                tv.setText(spin);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In this program, i'm trying to display selected options from the Spinner to the TextView. But output dsiplays **android.widget.Spinner@44c0d7f8**

I want output like (1,2,3,4 or 5) as the option selected in Spinner rather than android.widget.Spinner@44c0d7f8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            String spin=s.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            tv.setText(spin);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 10):

You dont need shared preference to load values in spinner. You just need to declare array in string.xml file and load that.I am giving you my code.Just use it.:-

## STEP-1:-

### Declare array for spinner in your string.xml(res->values->strings.xml):--

```
<string-array name="country_array">
    <item>Greece</item>
    <item>United Kingdom</item>
    <item>Italy</item>
    <item>France</item>
    <item>Germany</item>
    <item>Turkey</item>
    <item>Poland</item>
    <item>India</item>
</string-array>
```

## STEP-2:-

### Declare Spinner widget in your layout xml file

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinCountry"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:popupBackground="@android:color/white"
     android:scrollbars="none"
     android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

## STEP-3:-

### Declare Spinner in your Activity

```
Spinner spinCountry;
spinCountry= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinCountry);//fetch the spinner from layout file
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources()
                    .getStringArray(R.array.country_array));//setting the country_array to spinner
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
//if you want to set any action you can do in this listener
spinCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    spinCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
                 View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
             try {

                  String select_item =parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                 } 
           catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

        }

    });
```

Comment: Care to explain this code-only answer with some more detail?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling toString() method on spinner to get the selection which is wrong. You need to call getSelectedItemPosition() method to get the selection.